# Cannot knit Rmd file since I changed the name of User directory

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am using R for windows on RStudio.
I recently changed the name of User directory for a reason, and it seems that the change is causing a problem in knitting Rmd file.

If I try to knit Rmd file, the following error massage appears:

> Error: invalid 
>   version specification 'find'
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In system(paste(shQuote(path), "--version"), intern = TRUE) :
>     running command '"C:/PROGRA~3/CHOCOL~1/bin/pandoc.exe" --version' had status 65535
>   Execution halted

I entered '"C:/PROGRA~3/CHOCOL~1/bin/pandoc.exe" --version' in cmd, it says

> Cannot find file at 'c:\users\MY OLD USER NAME\appdata\local\pandoc\pandoc.exe'

So, I guess that knitr or pandoc is trying to find the wrong path. 
How can I fix the problem? How can I change the path?

Here is the list of what I have tried:

- Uninstalled R and RStudio, and then installed them.
- Then, I installed all the packages needed by `install.packeges`.

  - Thus, I am using the latest version of R, RStudio, and packages.
- Searched 'pandoc' in registry editor, and tried to find the old path (but I couldn't)

Comment: How exactly did you change the name of the directory? Did you simple rename it? Did you modify environment variables like `%USERPROFILE%`? Did you consider creating a new user profile instead of using the (broken?) profile with the (somehow) changed directory name?

Comment: >CL Thanks for your response, I used registory editor to rename User directory, and modified the name of environment variables. But, the suggestion by Yihui Xie below solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you installed Pandoc by yourself through Chocolatey, and the installation was broken after you changed the name of your User directory.

First, [you do not have to install Pandoc separately if you are using RStudio](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html), because RStudio has bundled Pandoc with it.

If you have to install Pandoc for some reason, you may need to reinstall it (perhaps you have to reinstall Chocolatey, too).

```
choco uninstall pandoc
choco install pandoc
```

Comment: You are right, I installed Pandoc through Chocolatey (I don't remember why). And, 'choco uninstall pandoc' solved the problem, thanks!